# Send only filled fields via GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Look at simple form below:**

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="price_min" >Min
    <input type="text" name="price_max" >Max
</form>
```

When I send form with filled only one field, in my url I get empty values for not filled keys

(ex. **`index.php?price_min=`**).

**Question:**

- How to remove empty keys from url?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse serialized string and remove blank values. Then you can use post to necessary api using jQuery.

#### Sample

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Ljmegmew/)

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var formjson = $("#frmTest").serialize();
  
  var result = formjson.split("&").filter(function(val) {
    return val.split("=")[1].length > 0;
  }).join("&")
  
  console.log("Serialized String:", formjson);
  console.log("Processed String:", result);
  
  // $.get('action.php', formjson, function(response){ ... })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmTest">
  <input type="text" name="price_min">Min
  <input type="text" name="price_max">Max
</form>

<button id="btn">Test Serialize</button>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to duplicate the data being sent to the console (because it does)?

Comment: @TylerH I just represented both values, serialized string and processed string. So you just have to use processed string.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to send the fields like this

```js
$('your_form').submit(function() {
   var min_price = $("#min_price").val();
   var max_price = $("#max_price").val();
   var string = "";
   if(min_price.length > 0){
      string += "min_price="+min_price
   }
  if(max_price.length > 0){
      string += "&max_price="+max_price
   }
   window.location.href = 'index.php?'+string;
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Updated the answer @FrédéricHamidi , thanks for the advice :)